# nrpe : Network server bind failure (98: Address already in use)

Tags: linux, monitoring, nrpe, icinga

I have installed `iCinga` and `nrpe` in same machine. I am using `nrpe` for monitor many linux machine, so I installed nrpe locally also.

When I start my nrep locally `service nrpe start` it sows error like in `/var/log/messages`

```
nrpe : Network server bind failure (98: Address already in use)
```

I have google it that issue, and find the 5666 port usage

```
[root@cosrh6-74 conf.d]# netstat -apn | grep :5666
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50539           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50608           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41987           10.104.16.210:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      1 127.0.0.1:42001           10.104.16.210:5666          SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50576           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41927           10.104.16.210:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52598           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52624           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41962           10.104.16.210:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41979           10.104.16.210:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52566           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41928           10.104.16.210:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52569           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41955           10.104.16.210:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52587           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50586           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50547           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52588           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50609           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50567           10.104.16.212:5666          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52592           10.3.81.172:5666            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 :::5666                     :::*                        LISTEN      757/xinetd
```

I I have changed `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` port to **56666** from **5666**.

How can I configure different port in host configuration(different port for different host) in **icinga2 server** to monitor machines with **nrpe** running in different ports?

Is this right to change port? Or any other way to do this? Please correct me if I did anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added port in `command.conf` file like this,

```
object CheckCommand "check-nrpe" {
    import "plugin-check-command"
    command  = ["/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe"]
     "-p" ="56666"
     "-H" ="$host$"
     "-c" = "$nrpe_command$"
     "-a" = $nrpe_arguments$"
}
```

**"-p" ="56666"** Works for me!!

**EDIT**:
Or we can pass like arguments from host configuration ( keeping port number in host configuration like @7171u answer) .

Answer (score 1):

In each host definition add:

```
vars.nrpe_port = <host_nrpe_port>
```

Ref: [docs.icinga.org](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/plugin-check-commands?highlight-search=nrpe#plugin-check-command-nrpe)

Comment: This is just a var right? how does this reflect in command execution.

Comment: Yes we can get this port from host config like address during command execution, anyway we need to give -p in command conf